# Shuffling questions from a csv file and putting numbers in front of them

Tags: java

I've got problem with shuffling questions and later putting numbers in front of them. Right now, the code below is getting questions and possible answers from csv file. It shuffles the choices and later on corrects answers and grades it. The code also stops when the person wants to.(I cut the code because it wasn't necessary)
  I tried to shuffle the questions but it didn't work(There's a visible code about me trying) and I've no idea how to number them. Any ideas are welcome!

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Scanner;


public class misasiseeon {

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    int questionsCorrect = 0;
    int questionsAnswered = 0;
    boolean finish = false;

    String splitBy = ",";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/FilePath"));
    String line = br.readLine();
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] b = line.split(splitBy);
        String question = (b[0]);
        String answer1 = (b[1]);
        String answer2 = (b[2]);
        String answer3 = (b[3]);
        String answer4 = (b[4]);
        String answer5 = (b[5]);
        String finish1 = (b[6]);

 ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<>();
 questions.add(question);
Collections.shuffle(questions);

        ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<>();
        vastused.add(answer1);
        vastused.add(answer2);
        vastused.add(answer3);
        vastused.add(answer4);
        vastused.add(answer5);
        Collections.shuffle(answers);

       System.out.println(questions);
     System.out.println(answers);
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to shuffle a list of only one question. Can you provide more code? Does shuffling the answers work? Can you provide an example of what you're getting, and what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You have declared and initialized the "questions" ArrayList within your loop. This recreates the ArrayList from scratch for every iteration of your loop. You would then be shuffling a list of 1 element each time. You should move the question ArrayList definition outside the loop.

Another problem is the association of the question with its answers. To do that you would be better off creating a new class called QuestionAndAnswers whose instance variables would hold a question and it's possible answers. Instead of separate lists for questions and answers, create an ArrayList of QuestionAndAnswers. Populate that list in the loop, then shuffle, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating and shuffling a List named `answers`, but you are adding answers to a List called `vastused`.

Change from this:

```
ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<>();
vastused.add(answer1);
vastused.add(answer2);
vastused.add(answer3);
vastused.add(answer4);
vastused.add(answer5);
Collections.shuffle(answers);
```

To this:

```
List<String> answers = new ArrayList<>();
answers.add(answer1);
answers.add(answer2);
answers.add(answer3);
answers.add(answer4);
answers.add(answer5);
Collections.shuffle(answers);
```

Also note change of `answers` type from `ArrayList` to `List` - see [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: I'd really like to add my whole code, but everything is in my native language and it would be hard to understand